# Find the smallest possible value of an equation, where $a+b+c=3$

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method

We have the positive real numbers $a, b, c$ such that $a+b+c=3$. Find the minimum value of the equation:

$$A=\frac{2-a^3}{a}+\frac{2-b^3}{b}+\frac{2-c^3}{c}$$

I solved it in the following fashion:

$$
\begin{align}
A&=2\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)-(a^2+b^2+c^2)\\
&\ge 2\cdot\frac{3^2}{a+b+c}-(a^2+b^2+c^2) \quad \textrm{(Andreescu inequality)}\\
&=2\cdot3-(a^2+b^2+c^2)\\
&=6-(a^2+b^2+c^2).
\end{align}$$

However, $9=(a+b+c)^2\ge 3(ab+bc+ac)$, so
$$3\ge ab+bc+ac.$$

From this we have that $A \ge 6-3=3$, where equality is true for $a=b=c=1$.

Due to the total simplicity of my solution, I have difficulties believing that it is correct, despite having checked it thoroughly many times. Could you please tell me if my solution is correct and suggest some alternative solutions?

Comment: Why woud simplicity scare you?  This was clearly designed to fit into symmetry nicely and so it should be no surprise that AM.GM or one of it's equivalence breaks it down nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is wrong because after your first step we need to prove that:
$$6-(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq3,$$ which is wrong for $a=2$.

We'll prove that $3$ is a minimal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that$$\frac{2(ab+ac+bc)}{abc}-(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq3$$ or
$$\frac{2(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)}{3abc}-\frac{9(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{(a+b+c)^2}\geq3$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^4b+2a^4c+6a^3b^2+6a^3c^2-22a^3bc+6a^2b^2c)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^4b+2a^4c-2a^3b^2-2a^3c^2+8a^3b^2+8a^3c^2-16a^3bc-6a^3bc+6a^2b^2c)\geq0$$ or
$$2\sum_{cyc}(a^4b-a^3b^2-a^2b^3+ab^4)+8\sum_{cyc}c^3(a^2-2ab+b^2)-3abc\sum_{cyc}(a^2-2ab+b^2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(2ab(a+b)+8c^3-3abc)\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$2ab(a+b)+8c^3\geq3\sqrt[3]{(ab(a+b))^2\cdot8c^3}\geq3\sqrt[3]{32}abc>3abc.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=c=1,$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Comment: I wouldn't say that that's the mistake, since the line with $6-(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ is correct but just not good enough for the claim. The mistake occurs somewhere in the missing reasoning in the vicinity of $3\ge ab+bc+ac$ (like why that's sufficient).

Comment: I was just saying that the actual mistake the asker makes is in the “from this”. The whole proof is correct up to and including the line $3\ge ab+bc+ac$ but right after that there must be a mistake in the unjustified jump (which can’t be justified for the reason you point out).

Comment: @TokenToucan It's enough to write, which i wrote. See please better my post.

Comment: Hello Mr Rozenburg, I have understood your solution implicitely, thanks a lot, however I cant understand how you thought of the fact that $(a-b)^2$ divides the polynomial displayed on the previous line. Could you please explain how you initially thought that $(a-b)^2$ divides it?

Comment: @Michael Christofer I added something. See now.

Comment: thanks a lot @Michael Rozenburg, have a good day

Comment: @Michael Christofer You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$A = 2\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)-\left[(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)\right]$$
$$=2(ab+bc+ca)\left(\frac{1}{abc}+1\right)-9.$$
Using know inequality $(ab+bc+ca)^2 \geqslant 3abc(a+b+c)$ and the AM-GM inequality, we get
$$A \geqslant 2\sqrt{3abc(a+b+c)}\cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{abc}}-9=3.$$
Equality occur when $a=b=c=1.$ So $A_{\min} = 3.$